# Запятая перед союзом И в сложносочиненном предложении.

Tags: пунктуация

Поясните, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед союзом И в предложении: " Внуки обрадуются этому, и покой снова вернётся в их детское сознание". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

" Внуки обрадуются этому, и покой снова вернётся в их детское сознание".-запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложносочинённом, общего члена нет.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначный ответ: запятая нужна!